# Send Push Notifications Through Proxy (APNs and GCM)

Tags: proxy, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have built both ios and android apps which will receive push notifications. The problems are NOT from device side but from server side.

Because our company's internal server must connect to external network through Proxy, when users send notifications to mobile devices, the server which handles sending notification request must send request to proxy server then proxy server forwards request to APNs and GCM.

I have no idea about how to send push notification requests through proxy. I have studies in this case for several days, but no solutions have been found.

I saw some guys said APNs does not allow connections coming from Proxy Server. Only direct connection is accepted. Is that true? Is there any official docs mentioned it?

Is there anyone able to help me？
I wanna know how to send push notification through proxy for ios and android.

Comment: I solved it by adding an extra server which builds and sends notification requests to Google and Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java.You can use javaApns [enter link description here](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/) for ios. I my self have problem right now  to get GCM to send through proxy on my Server local it works. If you can you can configure the application server to send through proxy.